# How to mock JSON file in Jest

Tags: javascript, json, jestjs, supertest

I am using Jest to test my API and when I run my tests, my JSON file `results.json` gets written to due to the following line in my API `app.js` (which I don't want happening):

```
fs.writeFile('results.json', JSON.stringify(json), (err, result) => {
    if (err) console.log('error', err);
});
```

This is what my Jest file looks like:

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('./app');


// Nico Tejera at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714786/query-string-encoding-of-a-javascript-object
function serialise(obj){
    return Object.keys(obj).map(k => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[k])}`).join('&');
}


describe('Test /addtask', () => {
    test('POST /addtask Successfully redirects if newDate and newTask filled in correctly', () => {
        const params = {
                    newTask: 'Example',
                    newDate: '2020-03-11'
        };
        return request(app)
            .post('/addtask')
            .send(serialise(params))
            .expect(301);
    });
});
```

I tried creating a mock of the JSON file and placed it outside the `describe` statement to prevent the actual `results.json` file being written to:

```
jest.mock('./results.json', () => ({ name: 'preset1', JSONtask: [], JSONcomplete: [] }, { name: 'preset2', JSONtask: [], JSONcomplete: [] }));
```

But this doesn't change anything. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have seen other solutions to similar problems but they don't provide the answer I'm looking for.

**EDIT:** Although not a very good method, one solution to my problem is to wrap the `fs.writeFile` within the statement

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
//code
};
```

although this would mean that `fs.writeFile` cannot be tested upon.

**NOTE:** I am still accepting answers!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the code you want to test has a hard-coded I/O operation in it, which always makes things harder to test.

What you'll want to do is to isolate the dependency on `fs.writeFile`, for example into something like a `ResultsWriter`. That dependency can then be injected and mocked for your test purposes.

I wrote an extensive example on a very similar case with NestJS yesterday under [how to unit test a class extending an abstract class reading environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286624/how-to-unit-test-a-class-extending-an-abstract-class-reading-environment-variabl/61322396#61322396), which you can hopefully adapt to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

`jest.mock(path, factory)` is for mocking JS modules, not file content.

You should instead mock `fs.writeFile` and check that it has been called with the expected arguments. [The docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) explain how to do it.